# I'm stuck in a user loop in Debian 10

Tags: loops, authentication, debian

I can't log in Debian 10 anymore. Everytime i type my password, i'm sent back to the login screen. I've tried several methods such as "chown" but the problem is, I have to use the Recovery Mode to do so, cause  when i launch a terminal from the login screen (using ctrl + alt + f3) I do not have access to a lot of commands, like ls, chown...

[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]

Here are two screens : the first one refers to the error when I start Debian ; the second screen is when i log into the terminal from the login ("commande introuvable" means "command not found")
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItcOy.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X0li.jpg

Comment: I think you should ask in "Unix and Linux" sister side (you find it, in the top right icon). You miss many programs (did you delete them? moved some directory?). If you remember what did you do (as superuser) before getting such errors, would help to recover.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Honestly i haven't done anything particular. I was working on a flutter app and my computer just shut down for no reason (i had at least 30% battery power remained).But I'll try your suggestion, thanks again!